# Function as a template for SwiftUI elements

Tags: swiftui

I would like to use this function as a template with immutable values in a SwiftUI layout but get the error Result of call to 'padding' is unused:

```
func keys (padding: CGFloat, text: String, color: Color?) {
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(color)
        .padding(.trailing, padding)
        .padding(.leading, padding)

    Text(text)
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is

```
func keys (padding: CGFloat, text: String, color: Color?) -> some View {
    Group {             // << or any other container you want
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(color)
            .padding(.trailing, padding)
            .padding(.leading, padding)

        Text(text)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}
```